# android split() or indexof()

Tags: android, string, split, indexof

hi to all
i have a couple of text lines where they look like this

```
You are a friend:
name= [1] 
From= [ 2011-02-28 07:00:52] 
To= [2011-03-17 07:01:02]
Link= [http://www.example.com]
type= [good] for some
```

and i want to read only the text that is between the brackets "[]" i would like to know the best way to read it is it by using split(string) or using indexof(string) is better and if there is an example that would be great and also can someone please explane to me how does this code read the text that is between the brackets

thank you

```
String s = addressString;
int be = s.indexOf('[');
int e = s.indexOf(String[] fields = s.substring(s.indexOf('['), s.indexOf(']'));
```

i figured out the code i posted it should be like this

```
String s = addressString;                                           
int be = s.indexOf('[');
int e = s.indexOf(']');                                             
String fields = s.substring(be+1, e);
```

but now i have another problem which i have more than one line so when i change it to String[] fields it gives me an error so how can i make it to read more than one line i tried a for loop but stil it only reads number 1 that is in between the brackets ...!!!

thank you

Comment: Something is wrong with the last line of code you posted at the bottom. The parens don't even balance, for one thing. It doesn't make sense, for another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String lines[] = {"You are a friend:", 
                  "name= [1]", 
                  "From= [ 2011-02-28 07:00:52]", 
                  "To= [2011-03-17 07:01:02]", 
                  "Link= [http://www.example.com]", 
                  "type= [good] for some"};
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{// your previous code, but use lines[i] instead of s }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the brackets are always at the beginning and end it's probably easier to do something like this:

```
String s = addressString;
String innerText = s.substring(1,s.length-1);
```

Comment: If you see the last example, "type= [good] for some" it's not this case.